# Performance implications to keep count of how many times user chose certain entity

Tags: sql-server, performance, scalability

We have a feature request where a said users choice of certain entity has to be recorded, this would be an integer that is incremented every time the user chooses that specific entity. This information is later used for ordering the said entities every time the user gets all its associated of the said entities.

Assuming that we are limited to sql server as our persistent storage and that we could have !millions of users and each user could have anywhere between 1 to 10 of those said entities, performance would quickly become an issue.

One option is to have an append only log table where the user id and entity id are saved every time a user chooses an entity and on the query side we get all the records and group by entity id. This could quickly cause the table to grow very large.

The other would be to have three columns consisting of user id, entity id and count and we would increment the count every time the user chooses the said entity.

The above two options are what I have been able to come up with.

I would like to know if there are any other options and also what would be the performance implications of the above solutions.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use option 2 unless there are vastly vastly more write operations than queries. However you do it, you have to store the users' choices somewhere. Option 2 is the straightforward SQL approach.

Answer (score 1):

If this was 2001 performance could be an issue.
If you are using SQL server 2012 or 2016 
then I say either are good.
Ints or Big ints index well and the performance hit would be insignificant.

You could also store the data in a xml or json varchar field

but I would go with your first option.

Using Big Ints and make sure you use indexes no matter what you do

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in the first option i will only use a log table which has a user id and entity id, so where would big int come in to play?

Comment: Plan to expansion, I miss read but if you are ever going to have more than 2.5 Billion   userid or items or number of records use BIG int, else start  your userid;s at - 2.5 billion so you have a full range from -2.5 - + 2.5